# return payload for a API Gateway AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway

I have created a lambda function in Python 3.6 to return few records to an API gateway. the return standard according to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html) must be:

```
{
  "isBase64Encoded" : "boolean",
  "statusCode": "number",
  "headers": { ... },
  "body": "JSON string"
}
```

However, I need to return the data cached from a list and parsed to a JSON format to returned in the required format but it's not going thru, apparently, I can't assign a variable to `body`:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   if event["httpMethod"] == "GET":
       param1 = event["queryStringParameters"]["param1"]
       param2 = event["queryStringParameters"]["param2"]


   info = redshift_get_output(param1,param2)
   payload = json.dumps(info)

   print(payload)

   outcome = {
    "isBase64Encoded": 'false',
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": { "header": "headerValue" },
    "body": payload
    }

   return outcome
```

When I run it like that I get in my API Gateway execution the success message but the body doesn't contain anything :(

[image]

Someone has a clue about how could I figure this out, please. thanks so much

Comment: Did `print(payload)` write anything to the Lambda log?

Comment: No it doesnt it was just to verify that Ièm really getting the string as I need but seems like I can't send my json data in a variable it must be something hardcoded :(

Comment: I can think of no reason why it wouldn't work.  I think your variable just happens to contain the JSON representation of an empty array.  Log it in the Lambda log, and verify.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually this is why i get a previous print to validate that is not coming empty and it's not so I really dont know why the API can not print it.

Comment: I asked you, previously, if `print(payload)` logged anything, and you said no, but now you say yes.  Is it logging or is it not logging?

Comment: Possible issue: change `"isBase64Encoded": 'false',` to  `"isBase64Encoded": False,`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured this out. The thing is that even if I apply a casting method for my payload to JSON the string that was returning always has at the beginning and at the end the square brackets `[]`.

I created a customer replace function to delete the brackets and pass to my return function the payload without `[]`.

Script:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text


def lambda_handler(event, context):

   if event["httpMethod"] == "GET":
       param1 = event["queryStringParameters"]["param1"]
       param2 = event["queryStringParameters"]["param2"]


   rep = {"[": "", "]": ""} 
   info = redshift_get_output(param1,param2)
   payload = json.dumps(info)
   payload = replace_all(payload,rep)


   print(payload)


   outcome = {
    "isBase64Encoded": 'false',
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": { "header": "headerValue" },
    "body": json.loads(payload)
    }

   return outcome
```

thanks so much